# How to understand scipy.stats.genextreme shape parameter

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

The [`scipy.stats.genextreme` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html) states:

> Note that several sources and software packages use the opposite convention for the sign of the shape parameter `c`.

Does this mean I can just multiply it by -1 and it is equivalent to the definition in these other sources. The documentation doesn't expand further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean I can just multiply it by -1 and it is equivalent to the definition in these other sources...

Yes.  For reference, the "other sources" includes the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution), where the shape parameter is ξ.  For SciPy, use c = -ξ.